# Databrick SCALA: spark dataframe inside function

Tags: scala, databricks

I have a databricks scala notebook. I am writing the following

```
var df=(some code to create the dataframe)

if (STRING1 == "testing"){

var df2=df.withColumn("New",lit("astring"))

}

df2.show()
```

and seems like I am not able to show df2, and df2 must be declare first ... how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you declare a variable inside the if statement, the scope is only available till the end of the if block.

So you could either move the df2 within the if block

```
var df=(some code to create the dataframe)

if (STRING1 == "testing"){
var df2=df.withColumn("New",lit("astring"))
df2.show()
}
```

or just declare df2 outside of the if statement

```
var df=(some code to create the dataframe)

var df2= if (STRING1 == "testing"){
df.withColumn("New",lit("astring"))
} else df
df2.show()
```

Comment: thanks. anyother workaround ? like declare an empty dataframe without data and column , just like var stringvar1: String = null

Comment: you could do that with  `spark.emptyDataFrame()`